# Xubuntu 22.04 RDP Remote Desktop

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

In Ubuntu Gnome, RDP is now the default protocol for Remote Desktop (& in my quick test, seems to work OK), but is the same possible in Xubuntu?  I’m guessing the answer’s “No”, but thought I’d ask anyway.

I’m connecting from either Manjaro Cinnamon (latest Remmina) or Ubuntu Gnome.

There are tutorials out there for `xrdp`, but I want to connect to the logged in session, not a new session.

Comment: The package `tigervnc-scraping-server` has a VNC server that lets you connect to the existing session.

Comment: I can still connect using `vino` like before the upgrade, & tbh I’ll probably keep doing that.. Just a bit strange that Xubuntu hasn’t joined the brave new MS world too.